# Python 3.8 crashing with c0000005 in idle

Tags: python

I have a script which was working completely fine until few days back. I was running this through task scheduler. I stopped getting mails so I checked the script. When I run that manually python got crashed. No changes were made from my side.

This script is reading an excel file with server hostnames, id, password of SQL server to connect using pyodbc. I checked and there is no problem with file read and data is present in the data frame.

When I put some logging, I came to find out that it is crashing when I am trying to connect to sql server. That connect statement is in a try catch block also.

```
for i in range(len(df)):
logging.error(f"Error: {i}")
try:
    logging.error(f"Error AB")
    print(df.head(2)) #DATA IS PRESENT
    con_query=f"DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};SERVER={df['hostname'][i]};DATABASE=master;UID={df['login'][i]};PWD={df['pwd'][i]};"
    logging.error(f"Error BC")
    print(con_query)
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(con_query,timeout=1)
    logging.error(f"Error AAA")

except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"{con_query} not worked")
```

The line which is failing is `cnxn = pyodbc.connect(con_query,timeout=1)`. Connections to sql server is working fine in my other scripts.

Output console:

```
ERROR:root:Error
ERROR:root:Error: 0
ERROR:root:Error AB
*Data frame details*
ERROR:root:Error BC
DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=****;DATABASE=***;UID=***;PWD=***;
```

Comment: Is `pyodbc.connect` throwing an exception? If so, does it say something about what problem it encountered? Are you sure the database is running and accessible?

Comment: Please extend the code in your question with the `except:` statement and statements below it.  Does the except not `raise` the exception? Not raising is very dangerous as it can completely hide major problems.

Comment: Except block is there but it is not reaching that

Comment: Python gets stopped running

Comment: You should put `raise` in the `except:` after the logging.error. Must be a crash inside the pyodbc dll - try searching the pyodbc issues, perhaps try https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Troubleshooting-%E2%80%93-Generating-an-ODBC-trace-log - are you using the l;atest version?

Comment: Yes, using the latest version

Comment: When I am running the programming manually using idle and click on run then there is no problem, except block is working fine like it should and a message is coming as output which I have put in the except block to show.

But when I am running the program directly by double clicking it is getting crashed.

This is for another program but similar situation.

Comment: @barny I tried hard to search a solution but couldnt find